# Fail to call API Gateway endpoints - Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, axios, cors, aws-api-gateway

I have a simple architecture (for testing purposes) running in AWS for a side project. My backend NodeJs application is running in an ec2 instance. My frontend is hosted on Vercel. My frontend will make an axios call to API Gateway, which routes based on the URL to the relevant endpoints of my EC2 accordingly.
For all GET request, the call goes through successfully. However for POST, PUT, PATCH and DELETE requests made from my frontend to the API Gateway, the console throws an error as such:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at  from origin  has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Here are my Codes for my Axios Instance:

```
const caseManagementController = axios.create({
  baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_CASE_MANAGEMENT_CONTROLLER,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});

const postOnePatientController = async (patientData: any) => {
  try {
    const response = await patientManagementController.post(
      `/createPatient`,
      patientData
    );

    console.log("Posted patient data: ", response.data);
    return response.data;
  } catch (err: any) {
    if (err?.response) {
      throw new Error(err.response.data.message);
    }
    throw err;
  }
};
```

Attached are also images of my API Gateway[[POST API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUGTO.png)][[OPTIONS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rtypx.png)]

I have tried calling the same endpoint in Postman with a POST request, and the call goes through with the expected results from my NodeJs Application. I'm thinking it could be an issue with the axios instance in my frontend, or a configuration issue in my API Gateway. I'm new to AWS services so I'm not sure if I've set up the gateway correctly. Do appreciate the help!